# Displaying he complete ArrayList?

Tags: java, json, arraylist

How do I get the complete list stored in my arraylist?
my json is

```
{"Children": [{"Child": {"childID": "1001","childName": "aaa","trackerID": "t1"}},{"Child": {"childID": "1002","childName": "bbb","trackerID": "t2"}}]}
```

code:

```
JSONObject json =new JSONObject(line);
int len=json.getJSONArray("Children").length();
System.out.println(len);              //len is 2
ArrayList Children=new ArrayList();
Map store=new HashMap();
String[] cid=new String[len];
String[] name=new String[len];
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    cid[i]=json.getJSONArray("Children").getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Child").get("childID").toString();
    name[i]=json.getJSONArray("Children").getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Child").get("childName").toString();
    store.put("ID", cid[i]);
    store.put("Names",name[i]);

}
Children.add(store);
System.out.println(Children);
```

The output i am getting is `[{Names=bbb, ID=1002}]`
but there are many more id's and names's.Expected output is `[{Names=aaa, ID=1001}],[{Names=bbb, ID=1002}]`
How can I print all of it ?

Comment: post your json also, and expected output, might be better solution available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{
Map store=new HashMap();
    cid[i]=json.getJSONArray("Children").getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Child").get("childID").toString();
    name[i]=json.getJSONArray("Children").getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Child").get("childName").toString();
    store.put("ID", cid[i]);
    store.put("Names",name[i]);
Children.add(store);

}

System.out.println(Children);
```

Just initialze the `Hashmap` inside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the key/value in the map store each time around the loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    ...
    store.put("ID", cid[i]); // always using key "ID"
    store.put("Names",name[i]); // always using key "Names"
}
```

You need to move

```
Children.add(store);
```

inside the for loop.

Having said that, do you really need to use store at all here?

Answer (score 0):

```
Children.add(store);
```

move this line in side for loop

Answer (score 0):

You store all elements into a Map with the same two keys ("ID" and "Names").

Try this:

```
store.put(cid[i], name[i]);
```